# How to close "Consider_importing_1_instead_2691"?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/enu/diagnosticMessages.generated.json.lcg#L978-L983

The project mix four file extensions, `js`, `jsx`, `ts`, `tsx`.

When I import `jsx` to `tsx`, VS Code warning `An import path cannot end with a '{0}' extension. Consider importing '{1}' instead.`.

Comment: What was the actual text of the warning and what was the code that triggered the warning?  Did you try the suggestion to remove the extension from the import path?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen The project mix four file extensions, js, jsx, ts, tsx. I try remove the extension, but an error occurred "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve".

Comment: That error message isn't coming from TypeScript.  If you're using another build tool such as Webpack, you'll need to configure it to try the proper extensions to find your file.

Comment: `// @ts-ignore` works. But I don't 
 known the error's name https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html

Comment: As the release notes say, describing the error being suppressed by `@ts-ignore` is just a suggestion for documentation purposes, so you don't need to worry about having the correct name.  Importing with the extension and using `@ts-ignore` is not an ideal solution since you don't get type information for the imported module; it would be better to remove the extension and fix your build system.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions works. Thank you, @MattMcCutchen